Kubuntu reboots after shutdown after installing RTL8852BE PCIe wifi
I have an HP Elite 8300 running kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with a usb wifi. I recently replaced the usb wifi with a RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller which the system immediately recognized. Since then I can't shut down or put the system to sleep because it reboots. I think it's a driver issue and I would need to reinstall it.
How can I reinstall it without creating new problems?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, not a driver issue. Check the firmware (UEFI) for any Wake on LAN or similar options.
